# Make Variable from names of variables that satisfy given condition

Tags: r

This is a very small subset of my data. I have over 20 thousand variables and 700 variables. What I am wanting to do is take a subset of the variables, and create a new variable that has the variables names for this subset that take a value of 1. *All the variables in these subset will be character variables.*

```
     id gen16 gen18 gen31 gen33 gen35 gen39 gen45 gen51 gen52 gen56 gen58 gen59 gen66 gen68
5962  1     1     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     1     2     2     2     1     2
6085  2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     1     2     2     2
6183  3     1     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2
6386  4     1     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2
6989  5     1     2     1     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2
7057  6     2     1     1     2     2     2     1     2     2     2     2     2     2     2
7276  7     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     1     1     2     2     2     1     2
7748  8     2     1     2     2     2     2     2     1     2     2     2     2     2     2
7917  9     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     1     2     2     2     2     2     2
8654 10     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     1     2     2
```

So this is what I am looking for.

```
     id gen16 gen18 gen31 gen33 gen35 gen39 gen45 gen51 gen52 gen56 gen58 gen59 gen66 gen68                  V1
5962  1     1     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     1     2     2     2     1     2 gen16, gen52, gen66
6085  2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     1     2     2     2               gen58
6183  3     1     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2               gen16
6386  4     1     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2               gen16
6989  5     1     2     1     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2        gen16, gen31
7057  6     2     1     1     2     2     2     1     2     2     2     2     2     2     2 gen18, gen31, gen45
7276  7     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     1     1     2     2     2     1     2 gen51, gen52, gen66
7748  8     2     1     2     2     2     2     2     1     2     2     2     2     2     2        gen18, gen51
7917  9     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     1     2     2     2     2     2     2               gen51
8654 10     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     1     2     2               gen59
```

I have written a for loop that does this, but I was wanting to avoid the loop since my data set will only get larger. My thought was to write a function what would work for one row, and then use the apply function to iterate it over the entire data set. I have had luck getting 2 different functions that work for one row, but have issues when trying to use them in the apply function.

These are the two other functions that I have written.

```
inf.type <- function(x) {
  foo <- as.data.frame(x[, c("gen16", "gen18", "gen31", "gen33", "gen35",
"gen39", "gen45", "gen51", "gen52", "gen56", "gen58", "gen59", "gen66", "gen68")] == 1)
  gentypes <- paste(names(foo[colSums(foo) == "1"]), collapse = ", ")

  return(gentypes)
}

inf.type <- function(x) {
  foo <- x[, c("gen16", "gen18", "gen31", "gen33", "gen35", "gen39", "gen45", 
              "gen51", "gen52", "gen56", "gen58", "gen59", "gen66", "gen68")]
  return(paste(names(foo[grep("1", foo)]), collapse = ", "))
 }
```

This two seem to work for a single row, but not when the apply function is used. If someone could help me figure out how to get one of these to work in the apply function, or has a better suggestion for a completely different approach, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should get the job done:

```
df$V1 = apply(df[,-1], 1, function(x) paste(names(which(x=='1')), collapse = ", "))
```

This looks at every row of `df[,-1]` (excluding `id` column), returns the indices (with `which`) that match `x=='1'`, extracts the `names` corresponding to those indices, and `paste` the names together for each row.

One can also write the following (with @alistaire's suggestion):

```
df$V1 = apply(df[, -1] == 1, 1, function(x) toString(names(x)[x]))
```

`df[, -1] == 1` turns `df[, -1]` into a logical matrix, with each cell evaluating to `TRUE` if it is equal to `1` and `FALSE` otherwise. One could then extract the `names` of those cells that is `TRUE` for each row, then concatenate the names together with `toString`.

**Result:**

```
     id gen16 gen18 gen31 gen33 gen35 gen39 gen45 gen51 gen52 gen56 gen58 gen59
5962  1     1     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     1     2     2     2
6085  2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     1     2
6183  3     1     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2
6386  4     1     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2
6989  5     1     2     1     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2
7057  6     2     1     1     2     2     2     1     2     2     2     2     2
7276  7     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     1     1     2     2     2
7748  8     2     1     2     2     2     2     2     1     2     2     2     2
7917  9     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     1     2     2     2     2
8654 10     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     1
     gen66 gen68                  V1
5962     1     2 gen16, gen52, gen66
6085     2     2               gen58
6183     2     2               gen16
6386     2     2               gen16
6989     2     2        gen16, gen31
7057     2     2 gen18, gen31, gen45
7276     1     2 gen51, gen52, gen66
7748     2     2        gen18, gen51
7917     2     2               gen51
8654     2     2               gen59
```

**Data:**

```
df = structure(list(id = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", 
"9", "10"), gen16 = c("1", "2", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", 
"2", "2"), gen18 = c("2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "1", "2", "1", 
"2", "2"), gen31 = c("2", "2", "2", "2", "1", "1", "2", "2", 
"2", "2"), gen33 = c("2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", 
"2", "2"), gen35 = c("2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", 
"2", "2"), gen39 = c("2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", 
"2", "2"), gen45 = c("2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "1", "2", "2", 
"2", "2"), gen51 = c("2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "1", "1", 
"1", "2"), gen52 = c("1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "1", "2", 
"2", "2"), gen56 = c("2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", 
"2", "2"), gen58 = c("2", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", 
"2", "2"), gen59 = c("2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", 
"2", "1"), gen66 = c("1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "1", "2", 
"2", "2"), gen68 = c("2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", 
"2", "2")), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("id", "gen16", "gen18", 
"gen31", "gen33", "gen35", "gen39", "gen45", "gen51", "gen52", 
"gen56", "gen58", "gen59", "gen66", "gen68"), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Comment: Works beautifully and matches the results of my loop! So much simpler than what I was trying. Thanks! I'm reading the documentation of the which function, but can you better explain exactly what it is doing for my future reference?

Comment: You can simplify a bit: `apply(df[, -1] == 1, 1, function(x) toString(names(x)[x]))`

Comment: @alistaire Good idea. I've added it as an alternative. Thanks.

Comment: @jamesguy0121 I've added some explanation for both my solution and alistaire's. Hope this helps!